# Turning off Animations AmCharts4

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

I want to turn off animations on my charts but it doesn't seem to be turning off. I removed 
"am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated)" from my code but everything seems to still be animated. Is there something I'm missing that could still activate the animations?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that adding 
`Series.showOnInit = false;` partially helped the issue, it reduce the lag/clunkyness of the page loading all the charts. But animations seem to be still working.

Comment: You should show the code of your chart, a codepen or jsfiddle in order someone could help you.